# Ember "Adapter Operation failed" error when 401 is returned in Ember 2.2.0.beta.3

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my Ember index route i use the RestAdapter to retrieve lots of "page"s:

```
/routes/index.js

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('page');
    }
});
```

When the previous model call for "page" will fail with error code 401 (auth failed), i am catching the error within the application route:

```
/routes/application.js

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        error: function(reason) {
            console.log('i am in here');
          this.transitionTo('login');
          return false;
        }
    }
});
```

But on the console i get a nasty error message, even when transitioning away to a saver page (login).

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/pages 401 (Unauthorized)send @ jquery.js:9664jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:9215(anonymous function) @ rest-adapter.js:764initializePromise @ ember.debug.js:52308Promise @ ember.debug.js:54158ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$default.extend.ajax @ rest-adapter.js:729ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$default.extend.findAll @ rest-adapter.js:356ember$data$lib$system$store$finders$$_findAll @ finders.js:123ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend._fetchAll @ store.js:947ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend.findAll @ store.js:923model @ index.js:4_emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend.deserialize @ ember.debug.js:25918applyHook @ ember.debug.js:52043HandlerInfo.runSharedModelHook @ ember.debug.js:50251_routerUtils.subclass.getModel @ ember.debug.js:50167(anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:51911tryCatch @ ember.debug.js:52258invokeCallback @ ember.debug.js:52273publish @ ember.debug.js:52241(anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:30835Queue.invoke @ ember.debug.js:320Queue.flush @ ember.debug.js:384DeferredActionQueues.flush @ ember.debug.js:185Backburner.end @ ember.debug.js:563Backburner.run @ ember.debug.js:685Backburner.join @ ember.debug.js:705run.join @ ember.debug.js:20147_emberMetalAssign.default.handleEvent @ ember.debug.js:45072exports.default._emberMetalMixin.Mixin.create._Mixin$create.handleEvent @ ember.debug.js:42009exports.default._emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend._bubbleEvent @ ember.debug.js:43089(anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:43031jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4670elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4338
application.js:5 i am in here
ember.debug.js:30877 Error: Adapter operation failed
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:26437:21)
    at Error.ember$data$lib$adapters$errors$$AdapterError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:65986:50)
    at ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$default.extend.handleResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:67290:16)
    at hash.error (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:67370:33)
    at fire (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3373:30)
    at Object.self.fireWith [as rejectWith] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3485:7)
    at done (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9541:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9943:8)
```

Actually I am landing on the login -page. But how do i get rid of the "Adapter operation failed" error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want `return this.transitionTo('login')` rather than `return false` in your application route `error` action. That's worked for me in the past.

Comment: works the same. still getting the AdapterError. inside the error(reason) action the reason holds the DS.AdapterError. Whatever I return, after transitioning to login i get the adapterError written out on the console. this seems dirty. ;>